# Semantic web database of music festivals?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm trying to use DBPedia to return a list of major British music festivals (specifically the ones defined in [this Wikipedia template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aMajor_British_Music_Festivals)) and their dates/locations over the last twenty years, however, am finding the actual data (particularly with regards to dates) to be somewhat limited.

Anyone know of a better resource than DBPedia for this kind of task? Alternately, is there some way of gathering this data with DBPedia that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know better RDF resources on British music festivals.
But, this is often when you get on a specific topic from a generic data source as DBPedia.
If you are passionate about something specific as "British music festivals" I suggest to build your own RDF dataset and publish it somewhere. Other people with your very same passion might come and help you.
If you know an website with all the information you need in HTML you might be able to get most of what you need simply 'scraping'. Is there such a website on 'British music festivals'?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the thoughts -- I may end up doing just that. Any suggestions for a good way to go about compiling RDF resources? I'm thinking I might create a wiki-ized Drupal install with all the semantic web stuff enabled -- any better ideas for maintaining such a resource? And there *is* a fan website for British festivals, but it has super spastic design and looks like it was pulled together in some WYSIWYG editor around 1997 -- there is no consistency at all to it.

Comment: For anyone arriving at this via Google and interested with what I did eventually, see: http://festivals.aendrew.com